# Type of the parameters passing in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures

how to check a parameter is string or number in stored procedure??
based on the incoming parameter type I want to work on the functionality 
for example:  if string i will search by name, if the number I will search by phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below whether this is helpful.

Check your input parameter using below sample function ISNUMERIC and if it returns 1 then it is numeric value. In your case it is phone number. else it is address.

SELECT ISNUMERIC('4567');

Comment: Yes,it is useful